# How to host and make public my own webapp

Tags: mysql, angular, server, web-development-server

It may be de dumbest question ever, but I cannot find a good answer that suits for me.
I'm so new in this world of web development, so I have little experience.

In college, we were asked to make our own webapp using Spring Tool Suite for backend and Angular for frontend, with a MySQL Database. If I want to run my app on my localhost, I must run the app in these three environments first, and it runs in http://localhost:4200.

Now my webapp is finished, and I want it to become public because I'd love my friends and family could see it.

I've no idea about port forwarding, or even servers. I'm sure there should be lots of tutorials on the Internet, but I might not be using the best words in Google to find them.

Please, me patient with me, as web development is really new for me.

Comment: Use a web hosting provider. You can probably start with their free tier or their lowest price option. Tons of hosting sites out there. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your stack, I think your best option would be a VPS. They go around for like $5/month and are not hard to set up, especially with the amount of online documentation there is.

In order to actually store and run your web application on the internet, you'll need a web server, which you can set up using a VPS. [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) has some good-quality servers and their documentation rocks. If you know how to use Linux, that's going to help you a lot!

- [Initial Server Setup with Debian 10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-debian-10) (I'm kind of biased towards Debian, but you can install Ubuntu and follow the docs for Ubuntu if you want)

Next you'll need to install MySQL.

- [How To Install the Latest MySQL on Debian 10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-latest-mysql-on-debian-10) (again, biased, but there are docs for every OS)

Then you'll need to install a web server, such as nginx:

- [How to Install Nginx on Debian 10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-debian-10)

Since you're working with Spring, you'll also have to install Java:

- [How To Install Java with Apt on Debian 10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-debian-10)

To build your frontend assets, you need to install Node.js:

- [How To Install Node.js on Debian 10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-debian-10)

(note: you'll have to handle the setup/dependencies and database migrations yourself, since this usually depends on how exactly your project is structured. Hopefully you're familiar enough with the CLI)

Once you've finished setting up your Spring application and built all your frontend assets (for production), you can [install it as a service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment-service).

Finally, you can use nginx as a reverse proxy to your Spring application. Here's a tutorial on how to do reverse proxying in nginx: `https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-reverse-proxy` (just make sure you add `http://127.0.0.1:4200` (or whatever your Spring app's production port is) for the `proxy_pass` parameter).

**Bonus:** You may want to set up SSL using Let's Encrypt/Certbot: `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-debian-10`

*I don't have enough reputation to post more than 8 links :(*

This is a very quick rundown on the minimal tasks you need to do to deploy your application. You do need some experience with the terminal and Linux, but with all these guides, it shouldn't be a problem. Feel free to ask if you get stuck anywhere!

Comment: I forgot to mention that you might want to have a domain name for this :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little awkward because during the development phase, you will essentially be running 2 separate projects on two separate web servers across two separate ports

Example:

- Backend API running on https://localhost:3000
- Front End Angular App running on https://localhost:4200 (consuming the API running on on `:3000`)

The important thing to understand is that in a production environment, you angular app is bundled into static files (thus, creating a `dist` folder).

Once the `ng build --prod` command is ran, the bundling process starts and you end up with your `dist` file (which is the only thing that needs to be deployed to the web server

The best way to work with this sort of setup is to get everything in one single project. Create a `wwwroot` or `clientapp` directory (name doesn't matter).

Once you deploy your project, make sure the produced `dist` directory exists so you can point your `index.html` document as the main document to render. Everything else should be taken care of for the most part.

I would suggest going through a tutorial with whatever your setup is. It will obviously be slightly different based on language and hosting platform:

- [Angular Deployment Docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)
- [Heroku](https://itnext.io/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147)
- [Azure](https://medium.com/ngconf/angular-on-azure-part-i-d842e8f76462)

You really shouldn't need to much server configuration to make this work. `index.html` is a default document on web servers. Meaning that if you have one present, it's automatically going to be rendered. The problem that you may run into is that you have to tell your webserver *where* to look for the `index.html`.

I would suggest trying to deploy your back-end project and try to just a simple `index.html` document to render. Once you have that, you should be able to just "plop" you dist folder in place of the index.html file and be up and running.

Answer (score -2):

There are numerous webhosting providers you can use those If your content is Static then to host your application for free there  is Heroku for example  . You just need to deploy code and servers setup, hosting and everything is done by heroku.You can also push your code through GitHub which is a great developer platform.